# kdb+ equivalent of SQL's rank() and dense_rank()

Tags: kdb

Any one every have to simulate the result of SQL's rank(), dense_rank(), and row_number(), in kdb+? Here is some SQL to demonstrate the features. If anyone has a specific solution below, perhaps I could work on generalising it to support multiple partition and order by columns -- and post back on this site.

```
CREATE TABLE student(course VARCHAR(10), mark int, name varchar(10));

INSERT INTO student VALUES  
('Maths', 60, 'Thulile'),
('Maths', 60, 'Pritha'),
('Maths', 70, 'Voitto'),
('Maths', 55, 'Chun'),
('Biology', 60, 'Bilal'),
('Biology', 70, 'Roger');

SELECT
 RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY course ORDER BY mark DESC) AS rank,
 DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY course ORDER BY mark DESC) AS dense_rank,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY course ORDER BY mark DESC) AS row_num,
 course, mark, name 
FROM student ORDER BY course, mark DESC;

+------+------------+---------+---------+------+---------+
| rank | dense_rank | row_num | course  | mark | name    |
+------+------------+---------+---------+------+---------+
|    1 |          1 |       1 | Biology |   70 | Roger   |
|    2 |          2 |       2 | Biology |   60 | Bilal   |
|    1 |          1 |       1 | Maths   |   70 | Voitto  |
|    2 |          2 |       2 | Maths   |   60 | Thulile |
|    2 |          2 |       3 | Maths   |   60 | Pritha  |
|    4 |          3 |       4 | Maths   |   55 | Chun    |
+------+------------+---------+---------+------+---------+
```

Here is some kdb+ to generate the equivalent student table:

```
student:([] course:`Maths`Maths`Maths`Maths`Biology`Biology; 
   mark:60 60 70 55 60 70; 
   name:`Thulile`Pritha`Voitto`Chun`Bilal`Roger)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you sort the table initially by course and mark:

```
student:`course xasc `mark xdesc ([] course:`Maths`Maths`Maths`Maths`Biology`Biology;mark:60 60 70 55 60 70;name:`Thulile`Pritha`Voitto`Chun`Bilal`Roger)
course  mark name
--------------------
Biology 70   Roger
Biology 60   Bilal
Maths   70   Voitto
Maths   60   Thulile
Maths   60   Pritha
Maths   55   Chun
```

Then you can use something like the below to achieve your output:

```
update rank_sql:first row_num by course,mark from update dense_rank:1+where count each (where differ mark)cut mark,row_num:1+rank i by course from  student

course  mark name    dense_rank row_num rank_sql
------------------------------------------------
Biology 70   Roger   1          1       1
Biology 60   Bilal   2          2       2
Maths   70   Voitto  1          1       1
Maths   60   Thulile 2          2       2
Maths   60   Pritha  2          3       2
Maths   55   Chun    3          4       4
```

This solution uses [rank](https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/rank/) and the [virtual index column](https://code.kx.com/q4m3/9_Queries_q-sql/#9322-the-virtual-column-i) if you would like to read up further on these.

Answer (score 2):

For table ordered by target columns:

```
q) dense_sql:{sums differ x}
q) rank_sql:{raze #'[(1_deltas b),1;b:1+where differ x]}
q) row_sql:{1+til count x}

q) student:`course xasc `mark xdesc ([] course:`Maths`Maths`Maths`Maths`Biology`Biology;mark:60 60 70 55 60 70;name:`Thulile`Pritha`Voitto`Chun`Bilal`Roger)

q)update row_num:row_sql mark,rank_s:rank_sql mark,dense_s:dense_sql mark by course from student
```

Answer (score 2):

I can think of this as of now:
Note: The rank function in kdb works on asc list, so I created below functions.
I would not xdesc the table, as I can just use the vector column and desc it

```
q)denseF
{((desc distinct x)?x)+1}
q)rankF
{((desc x)?x)+1}

q)update dense_rank:denseF mark,rank_rank:rankF mark,row_num:1+rank i by course from student
```

| course | mark name | dense_rank | rank_rank | row_num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Maths | 60 Thulile | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| Maths | 60 Pritha | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| Maths | 70 Voitto | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| Maths | 55 Chun | 3 | 4 | 4 |
| Biology | 60 Bilal | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| Biology | 70 Roger | 1 | 1 | 2 |